# I need a intrrupt handler for two serial port with c++ in lunux

Tags: linux, event-handling, serial-port, interrupt

Hello

I have a two serial port in my program.
I have class for serial port initializing and function.
when i send my serial port to function open it.
but when i send another serial port information and set interrupt handler in this function ، the first serial port cant receive with interrupt handler.

```
serial_port_init::serial_port_init(char *sp_name,speed_t baud,void (*event_func)(int32_t)){
struct termios termAttr;
struct sigaction saio;
sp = open(sp_name, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
saio.sa_handler = (event_func);
saio.sa_flags = 0;
saio.sa_restorer = NULL;
sigaction(SIGIO,&saio,0);

fcntl(sp, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
fcntl(sp, F_SETOWN, getpid());
fcntl(sp, F_SETFL,  O_ASYNC );

tcgetattr(sp,&termAttr);
cfsetispeed(&termAttr,baud);
cfsetospeed(&termAttr,baud);
termAttr.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
termAttr.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
termAttr.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
termAttr.c_cflag |= CS8;
termAttr.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
termAttr.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
termAttr.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
termAttr.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
tcsetattr(sp,TCSANOW,&termAttr);
tcgetattr(sp, &termAttr);
```

I call serial port initialize with

```
serial_port_init link_sp(link_usart_addr,link_usart_baud,&link_get_all_data_event);
```

and now I need a intrupt for both of them.
THANKS

Comment: *"I need a intrrupt [sic] handler for two serial port..."* -- No, you do not.  The kernel already has interrupt handlers for these devices.  Application programs do not have interrupt handlers for devices.  Apparently you're asking a [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: how can use it for run some function.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
static void handler(int sig)
{
    printf ("Hello world from handler\n");
}

serial_port_init link_sp(link_usart_addr,link_usart_baud,&handler);
```

Comment: when I define handler static Qt say undefined

Comment: Pls Post the Compiler message

Comment: I have two handler. one of them print "yas" and the second one print "hassan" but when I send a bit for first handler. the handler does not work but for second serial port it is work very well and print "hassan"

Comment: Do they run on different Ports